# Weird syntax error in Xcode based on file type

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode, openal

I have a C header with this function:

```
OSStatus MyGetDataFromExtAudioRef(ExtAudioFileRef ext_file_ref, const AudioStreamBasicDescription* restrict output_format, ALsizei max_buffer_size, void** data_buffer, ALsizei* data_buffer_size, ALenum* al_format, ALsizei* sample_rate);
```

I can `#include` this header in an Objective-C file and compile fine.

If I change that same Objective-C file to a `.mm` suffix rather than `.m` and verify that it is now identified as Objective-C++ source, I get a compiler error that says `Expected ')'` on the line above. While not clear, it seems to be placing the source of the error on the word `output_format` parameter.

There is nothing in the above function that appears to be bad syntax, with regards to parenthesis, and I can't understand why this one change should make any difference.

Does anything jump out at anyone here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, the `restrict` keyword isn't part of the C++ standard, so the C++ compiler (that is used to compile Objective-C++ code) doesn't recognize it.

Comment: There is an `extern "C" {` at the top that should prevent it being compiled as C++ right? I just checked to verify that. But I had it commented out. I uncommented that out, and now the C++ compiler fails with the same parenthesis error for the `extern "C" {` -- is this phrase also not a C++ standard?

Comment: it would appear as though this issue is not unusual for others in similar positions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376003/linker-error-using-extern-c-in-objective-c-code I may just have to experiment with a variety of settings

Comment: @SebbyJohanns No, `extern "C"` will only change the way the name of the symbol is mangled to allow C++ code to link against C code (or client C code to link against parts of your C++ code). It will still be compiled using the C++ compiler.

Comment: ok so the `restrict` is going to be handled by the C++ compiler no matter what, and there is no good way around it?

Comment: @SebbyJohanns `#ifdef __cplusplus\n#define restrict\n#endif`